# MySQL unique index doesnt apply when values are NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, unique-key

I have a table for detecting views of articles - it should have one unique row for each `article_id&&NULL&&IP` when noone is logged in and unique row for each `article_id&&loggedInUser&&IP`. 
So I thought that when noone is logged in I will just add a NULL instead of user_id. But MySQL suprised me - when I've added UNIQUE KEY like `article_id&&user_id&&IP` it worked fine for logged in users, but if no user logged in it started to add rows like (e.g.):

```
article_id   |   user_id   |   IP
   5               NULL      192.168.3.50
   5               NULL      192.168.3.50
   5               NULL      192.168.3.50
   5               NULL      192.168.3.50
```

This doesnt seem much unique - I know it is caused by NULL but how to solve this? Should I just rely on the fact that no user will have user_id "0"?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put the create table syntax in the info?

Comment: This is intentional and documented - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html ."a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL" . I would possibly use 0, or set up a 'none' userid in case you use 0 for other purposes (ie, I often convert numeric id input fields to their int equivalent which might be 0 if someone is playing around and then I likely do not want 0 to be valid).

Comment: @Kickstart please describe overall problem a bit more - it could be a nice answer :)

Comment: You could use a special id for the null user... 0 for instance?

Comment: @Perroloco well thanks but I ve already suggested that in my question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional and is documented:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

*A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. **This constraint does not apply to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine.** For other engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.*

While you could use a user id of 0 I would be concerned that you might have 0 used elsewhere when you do not want a record found. For example I often just convert any input id field to an integer and if someone has tried to hack around and enter a string this might well be converted to 0. In such a case I wouldn't really want the zero to be meaningful.

I would possibly be tempted to set up a 'none' userid to use in this situation.

Comment: 1) it cant be hacked around since its a pure inside PHP thing 2) even if so it would be just counted as unlogged user - and thats fine 3) as fore 'none' I have thought about that, but it seems to me to keep with the integers, however thanks for deep description :)

Comment: Just meant that you land up possibly showing them real data if someone attacks the script and manages to pass in something that is translated to a 0. As to none, I meant a user record for a generic user. Could be id 1, or any other number.

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is going to grow huge very quickly and provide very little benefit. If it were me I would just rely on [analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) to handle this sort of data. If you really want this it can be done very easily by adding one more field to your table for a count. When you are about to add a row to this look for one which already exists. If one does then instead of adding a new record just update the current record and increment the count instead. This will provide the exact same information in much less space.